# regex replace the basic @username and #hashtag with some special cases

Tags: regex, emoji

Stuck on a new case in a regex match...
I have a string that contains words, #hashtags, @useranmes, and other misc characters.

Some examples as they get messier and messier. 'My New Car' is often optional, and won't exist, as this is a preg replace, I will end in an empty string, which in my case, is desirable.  But if 'My New Car' does exist, that would be the resulting desired string

1. My New Car #wheels #car #auto #drive #weekend
2. My New Car #wheels #car #auto #drive #weekend @me
3. My New Car #wheels, #car, #auto, #drive, #weekend
4. My New Car #wheels, #car, #auto, #drive, #weekend, @me
   ( All of the above, without 'My New Car ', usual mess-up of double spacing etc. )
   ( Then people get fancy and add in emoji in the string
5. My New Car #wheels #car \ud83d\ude2d\ud83d\ude2d\ud83d\ude2d\ud83d\ude02

Desired Result:
1. My New Car
2. My New Car
3. My New Car
4. My New Car
5. My New Car

I was doing pretty good with `(^|\s)[#@](\w+)` and then the emoji came into play as well as the funny squares  which are represented as \ue412\ue412

I think I only need find a way to say if starts with \ remove to the end. I thought to go the other way, and negate anything not [a-zA-Z0-9] but this is multi-language as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your examples are strange.. If you only want My New Car you just remove all after #. But apparently there is something else you want which you are not telling us - or that I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry, 'My New Car' is not always in the front. [#this #that Hi how are you? #tag #more \ud83d\ude2d @foobar, #tagit #tags] What is in brackets, not including the brackets, it about as messy as it would get in English.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?:[#@]\S+|\\\S+)
```

works with all your examples, including the "messy" one.

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks!  I think this may be an issue that has to do with php and json_decode.  A section of the json looks like this "text": "#emoji convos \ud83d\ude2d\ud83d\ude2d\ud83d\ude2d\ud83d\ude02", but when I pass that to json_decode() in php, view source in a browser, that is not at all what I get, I get the actual emoji character.  In that case, I don't know how to perform regex on it. I could only do it before I decode the json, but there is too much data imo to do so.

Comment: Yeah, same problem as I am having.  Your regex I believe would work, it appears to when I compare it to the plain text I posted, which is the result of curl'ing some data from a url.  But once I pass it through json_decode() in php, something happens to the data to change it.  I will have to explore what is going on here.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `json_decode` function will turn the ascii escape sequences into the actual utf-8 unicode characters.

```
$t = "My New Car #wheels #car \ud83d\ude2d\ud83d\ude2d\ud83d\ude2d\ud83d\ude02";
$s = json_decode("\"$t\"");
var_dump($s);
```

Output:

```
string(40) "My New Car #wheels #car "
```

To consider these characters in `preg_replace` you need to turn on the `/u` unicode flag

```
$r = preg_replace("/\s*([#@]\S+|[^\\x00-\\xff])\s*/u", "", $s);
var_dump($r);
```

Output:

```
string(10) "My New Car"
```

The `\x` escape code from 0-127 (hex 00-ff) matches ascii characters. Anything higher than `\xff` is a utf-8 charcter.